# Mobile device screen resolution statistics?

Tags: mobile, usability

Are there any statistics (or an industry standard) for mobile device screen resolutions?

I'm optimising a site for mobile. So far I've just used one media query and it works fine down to about 240px wide, but messes up a bit after that. I'd love to know what's the smallest size worth accommodating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of these articles are getting on a bit time-wise, but for reference:

http://sender11.typepad.com/sender11/2008/04/mobile-screen-s.html

http://blog.wapreview.com/416/

http://cartoonized.net/cellphone-screen-resolution.php

I'd second paulmorriss' findings that these days, the chances of someone using a sub 240px handset are pretty slim.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best thing is to see the resolution for existing visitors. You can install Google analytics (if you haven't already), then on the Visitors / Mobile / Devices report you can select other/screen resolution (new version) or Visitors / Mobile / Mobile Devices and change Operating System to screen resolution.

When I ran it on our site (2000 visits, so not a big sample) I found only 3 visitors less than 240 - the smallest being 214.

Comment: I dont have much data to work from for my site yet, but thats for sharing yours.

Answer (score 1):

It really does depend on what area your visitors are from.  Check out [Opera Mini's stats](http://www.opera.com/smw/) and [Admob's stats](http://metrics.admob.com/) for their most popular devices by country. It really does vary widely by region.